# Why is my @ExceptionHandler annotated method not called when the @PathParam is not valid?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, bean-validation

Using Spring Boot, I have an interface which includes the method declared as

```
@GET
@Path("/{name}")
ProductResponse find( @Size(min = 3) @PathParam("name") String name) throws BusinessException;
```

and a Rest controller annotated with @Validated, implementing the above interface.
The controller also implements the method

```
@ExceptionHandler(value = { ConstraintViolationException.class })
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
public String handleResourceNotFoundException(ConstraintViolationException e) {
     Set<ConstraintViolation<?>> violations = e.getConstraintViolations();
     StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
     for (ConstraintViolation<?> violation : violations ) {
           strBuilder.append(violation.getMessage() + "\n");
     }
     return strBuilder.toString();
}
```

Also the @configuration annotated class includes the method

```
@Bean
public MethodValidationPostProcessor methodValidationPostProcessor() {
    return new MethodValidationPostProcessor();
}
```

This works for all requests but the issue is that when the request contains a name that does not meet the constraint, the method handleResourceNotFoundException is not called.

Yet, in the console i see the ConstraintViolationException

```
    [some omitted]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_121]
Caused by: javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: null
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationInterceptor.invoke(MethodValidationInterceptor.java:136) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at com.ncr.nep.sdk.service.aspect.PayloadValidationInterceptor.invoke(PayloadValidationInterceptor.java:103) ~[nep-sdk-service-1.19.0-GA.jar:1.19.0-GA]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at com.ncr.nep.sdk.service.aspect.ExceptionInterceptor.invoke(ExceptionInterceptor.java:41) ~[nep-sdk-service-1.19.0-GA.jar:1.19.0-GA]
    ... 95 common frames omitted
```

So why is the handling method not called and 500 is returned as the Response code? What am I missing?

Comment: what is the omitted part of stack trace? "Caused by" does not (necessarily) tell what is the exception that got thrown.

Comment: also, it is relevant as to how your controller is annotated, you left that out

Answer (score 1):

You're using JAX-RS (`@GET`, `@Path`, `@PathParam`, ...) with Spring's `@ExceptionHandler`. My guess is that that combination doesn't work. So either you should rewrite your controller using Spring:

```java
@GetMapping("/{name}") // Replacement of @Path and @GET
// @PathVariable replaces @PathParam
ProductResponse find( @Size(min = 3) @PathVariable("name") String name) throws BusinessException {
    // ...
}
```

Be aware that not all Spring annotations work on interfaces, so you may have to move them to the actual implementation.

Or alternatively, you can use JAX-RS's [`ExceptionMapper`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/ExceptionMapper.html):

```java
@Component
public class ConstraintViolationExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<ConstraintViolationException> {

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(ConstraintViolationException e) {
        Set<ConstraintViolation<?>> violations = e.getConstraintViolations();
        StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for (ConstraintViolation<?> violation : violations ) {
            strBuilder.append(violation.getMessage() + "\n");
        }
        return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity(strBuilder.toString()).build();
    }
}
```

In this case, if you're using Jersey, make sure to register the exception mapper in your `ResourceConfig` implementation.

Comment: note to OP, this is the part that is JAX-RS: `@GET
@Path("/{name}")`

Comment: Going along with your second suggested alternative I 1) added the ConstraintViolationExceptionMapper but did not annotate it with \@Component, 2) in my \@Configuration annotated class i replaced the factory method for creating MethodValidationPostProcessor (see in my question) with: \@Bean
    public ExceptionMapper<ConstraintViolationException> constraintViolationExceptionMapper() {
     return new ConstraintViolationExceptionMapper();
    } Yhis factory method is called but when the Constraint is caught the method in ConstraintViolationExceptionMapper is not called. Any suggestions?

Comment: @inor did you check my last paragraph? If you're using Jersey, I guess you have a `JerseyConfig` class somewhere. Make sure to register the mapper in there (eg. `register(ConstraintViolationExceptionMapper.class)`).

Comment: there is no JerseyConfig (nor ResourceConfig) in the classpath. I'm using Spring Boot and new at it so either i need to add some dependency to my pom or i need to figure out what IS currently being used [for the controller? servlet?]

Comment: You didn't define a `JerseyConfig` by yourself? Normally you don't have access to `@GET`, `@Path`, ... annotations unless you add a JAX-RS provider to your classpath such as **spring-boot-starter-jersey**.